# Is it possible to import bootstrap and all its requirements in 1 file?

Tags: html, bootstrap-5

I would like to know if it possible to use `<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.1/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" ></script>` instead of adding so many files?
[The bundle.js file](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/getting-started/introduction/).

Like the popper js etc..

Comment: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/getting-started/introduction/#bundle

Comment: Yes but it doesn't work and I don't know why so I thought that you needed all the files.

Comment: What doesn't work? Are you also using the CSS?

Comment: No do I need to add it?

Comment: Yes, CSS and JS are completely separate. The JS doesn't magically include the CSS. Check out the [getting started docs](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/getting-started/introduction/). The bundle.js includes all the required JS files, but the CSS needs to be included too. If you only want to use Bootstrap styles, but not the components you can use the CSS alone w/o the JS.

Comment: Thanks @Zim I didn't realize that. Cause it said it was a bundle..

Answer (score 0):

Bootstrap CSS and JS are completely separate. The Bootstrap JS doesn't magically include the CSS. Check out the [getting started docs](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/getting-started/introduction/).

The `bootstrap.bundle.js` includes all the required JS files (bootstrap.js and popper.js), but the CSS needs to be included too. If you only want to use Bootstrap styles, but not the components you can use the CSS alone w/o the JS.

Answer (score -1):

Use only that file which you needed. Example if you don't need popper then don't include popper.js file

Comment: I actually need  all of them so I want to add all of it with 1 file only